# Office365 REST API - Get contacts from both My Contacts and Directory

Tags: api, rest, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I've managed to get the list of user contacts back using the Office365 API, but I wondered whether there is a way of also returning the Directory contacts?

Answer (score 0):

The Contacts API doesn't access the directory. To get that information, you would use the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj126255.aspx).